# What are some techniques to avoid flow disruption during a complete redesign?

Tags: redesign, intranet, older-users

I'm working on a team that will be redesigning an internal website that's been live since the early 2000's. The design has not been updated in that time, only content. I'm wondering if there are any specific techniques that can be implemented into the research process to ensure that user flow is disrupted as little as possible when transitioning into the new site.

The new site will be completely redesigned in order to make it mobile-friendly and appease new users, though a large percentage of employees working at this company have been using this particular design since it's implementation. Specifically, I'm interested in learning particular techniques that can be implemented during the research and design process in order to keep flow disruption to a minimum for employees that are used to the current design.

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you focus on a specific UX problem you're trying to solve rather than a general "How can I appease [users who prefer the old site]?"

Comment: Hey Andrew, I tried to add more clarification, let me know if there's any more information you think I should add.

Comment: This is still too broad. You're effectively asking us to redesign a whole website.

Comment: I re-wrote the question, hopefully in a more articulate and concise way. I'm definitely not asking for a redesign of the website, just if there are any particular techniques (or literature) regarding minimization of flow disruption for users who have been using the website for a number of years and are used to the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only get resistance if your redesign does not allow them to achieve their goals.

So User research is your friend. Analytics alone will not give you all the answers.

You first need to find out what their goals are, and what they like and don't like about the old system.

It might even be a good idea to invite some employees into a committee too (they will feel part of the redesign and will become good UX advocates, which can help with other things in the future). Intranets impact all employees so its best to follow collaborative design with some of them to help redesign this.

You still remain the lead designer, but employees play a part in helping with that design.

Comment: +1 for discovering user goals. Try on-site observations to see what people do - on your site and off of it - and to see what's repetitive, what's difficult, what's easy. That reveals what the problems are. Then design your solutions to address the problems.